# How to write out odd numbers in an interval using for function

Tags: c#, for-loop

So my homework is I have to take two numbers from the user then I have to write out the odd numbers in that interval.But the code under doesn't work. It writes out "TrueFalseTrueFalse".

```
int szam;
int szam2=0;
int szam3=0;
int szam4=0;
Console.Write("Please give a number:");
                szam = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Please give another number:");
                szam2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (szam>szam2)
                {
                    for (szam3=szam, szam4 = szam2; szam4 < szam3; szam4++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(szam2 % 2==1);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (szam3 = szam, szam4 = szam2; szam3 < szam4; szam3++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(szam3 % 2 ==1);
                    }
                }
```

So if the two numbers would be 0 and 10, the program has to write out 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. You posted code. Is it not working? What's it doing different than the intended behavior?

Comment: You need to use `if` statements to determine if the number is odd or even then write the number to the console not the result of the comparison.

Comment: @itsme86 Sorry, so the code does not work and it writes out "TrueFalseTrueFalse". I could use some help with it.

Comment: @juharr It has to write out the odd numbers from the interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be careful when naming your variables yes its a small piece of code but it gets confusing to people trying to read it.

Based on the requirement, I would guess you want all the odd numbers given a certain range.

```
const string comma = ",";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int start = getNumber();
    int end = getNumber();
    if(start > end)
    {
        int placeHolder = end;
        end = start;
        start = placeHolder;
    }
    string delimiter = string.Empty;
    for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        if(i % 2 == 1)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Concat(delimiter,i.ToString()));
            delimiter = comma;
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();//otherwise you wont see the result
}
static int getNumber()
{
    Console.Write("Please enter a number:");
    string placeHolder = Console.ReadLine();
    int toReturn = -1;
    if (int.TryParse(placeHolder, out toReturn))
        return toReturn;
    return getNumber();
}
```

as Juharr mentioned in the comments, you need to check the result to print the actual number.

Comment: yip, only used static int getNumber() to provide some error handling, in case they want to get clever and enter "abc" as the start or end

Comment: So if I am understanding it right, I can leave out the last part and I won't have errors and the program would work just fine?

Comment: That's difficult to answer - depends on the context. I would suggest changing it to Console.Write("Please enter a number: "); int start = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); and the same for end if you are not concerned about error handling. That said error handling is always a better idea... If I were you I would include getNumber() but that is my opinion. In the code above we are only populating 2 variables. I believe they (lecturers/teachers) want to see an understanding of loops and control flow statements

Answer (score 0):

Width Linq you can write:

```
int szam = 20;
int szam2= 30;

var odds = Enumerable.Range(szam2 > szam ? szam : szam2, Math.Abs(szam-szam2))
.Where(x=>x % 2 != 0);
```

outputs:

**21 
23 
25 
27 
29**

```
// so we create a range from low to high (Enumerable.Range(..)
// take only the odd values (x % 2 != 0)
```

simply wrap it in string.Join to make a single string:

```
  string text = String.Join(",",Enumerable.Range(szam2 > szam ? szam : 
                szam2,Math.Abs(szam-szam2))
                .Where(x=>x % 2 != 0));
```